# Adding existing project to a project on Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#

I add to a new project existing project and I add the project reference too, but when I add a show of a class from the existing project- the project doesn't recognize it. For example-i open new project TripProject and I add to this project existing project TripCode containing class Person. I add the project reference to TripProject but when I try to make a show for Person it doesn't recognizes it.

Comment: Is `Person` a `public` class? And did you specify the namespace in which `Person` is declared with a `using`-statement in the code where you want to use `Person`?

Comment: Thank you. Class Person didn't public.

Answer (score 1):

Formalizing my comment as an answer:

Make sure that `Person` is a `public` class, and also that you specify the namespace in which `Person` is declared with a `using`-statement in the code where you want to use `Person`.